# Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'CreateRandomAnswersForKey' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)?

Tags: c#, .net, reference

It has been a long time since I've coded, but I am at a complete loss here even though I know it's some sort of simple mistake. Can anyone help me out? My error is Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'CreateRandomAnswersForKey' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

'''
using System;

namespace TestABRandomness
{
class Test
{
public static bool[] AnswerKeyArray;

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        AnswerKeyArray = new CreateRandomAnswersForKey();
    }

    bool[] CreateRandomAnswersForKey()
    {
        bool[] returnArray = new bool[100];
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            returnArray[i] = rand.Next(2) == 1;
        }

        return returnArray;
    }
}
```

}
'''

Comment: `CreateRandomAnswersForKey` isn't a class or struct - it's a method - so you can't `new` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method "Main" is a static method, so method CreateRandomAnswersForKey also needs to be static. You cannot call an instance method from a static method without specifying the instance.
And as John already wrote, you need to remove the "new" keyword in the method call.